# Magento: Bulk update categories' CMS block & Display Mode

Tags: magento

I want all categories to have Display Mode = "Products & CMS Block" & CMS Block = "some filter block".

I've seen [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/how-to-apply-a-categorys-display-setting-to-all-categories) but it doesn't solve the problem.

I've changed values in DB table

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_flat_store_1` SET display_mode = 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE', landing_page = 4;
```

// 4 is the id of the cms block

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_varchar` SET value = 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE' WHERE attribute_id = 49
```

// 49 is id of display_mode attribute.

And it didn't work. I can do it programatically also, there are not so many categories but enough to not do this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to fill 2 category tables:

First, insert the display mode for those categories which doesn't have them.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value) SELECT '3', '49', 0, entity_id, 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE' FROM `catalog_category_entity`
```

// 49 is attribute_id for display_mode

Then insert the block_id which you want to display.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value) SELECT '3', '50', 0, entity_id, '4' FROM `catalog_category_entity`
```

// 50 is the attribute_id For 'landing_page', value = 4 is the block id.

For those categories which already have values change INSERT IGNORE for REPLACE.

reindex catalog_category_flat.(in a command line, in project's /shell folder run php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat)

Done.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to update the flat file. cause the flat file will be updated through re-indexing. do re-index using ssh and make sure to check your error.log for possible issues.

Comment: Got it. But there's a problem: there are no records for categories which display "products only". Do I need to generate these in `catalog_category_entity_varchar` & `catalog_category_entity_int`? how?